# Why did my HDD stop working, what happening?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, windows

I have a HDD **external** and I am using it for about 3 months, I always used it in Ubuntu **20.04** and everything was great until yesterday I put it on a windows laptop, the windows laptop could not read it and now I put it on my Ubuntu and it does not read it either, what happened ?

I used this command in Ubuntu:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

And this is the result, but it does not work.

```
$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully.
```

I want to use it again on my Ubuntu, and sometimes in Windows.

**More information**

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for my_user: 
Disk /dev/sdb1: 1,82 TiB, 2000396746752 bytes, 3907024896 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6e697373

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1p1      1936269394 3772285809 1836016416 875,5G 4f QNX4.x 3rd part
/dev/sdb1p2      1917848077 2462285169  544437093 259,6G 73 unknown
/dev/sdb1p3      1818575915 2362751050  544175136 259,5G 2b unknown
/dev/sdb1p4      2844524554 2844579527      54974  26,8M 61 SpeedStor
```

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Disk information:

[image]

[image]

I tried to mount after that repair filesystem:

[image]

I tried to mount:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Is it an external hdd? what ubuntu version are you using? I cannot use it means is giving you errors? if you try it with  "disks" application does it see the drive?

Comment: You probably shut down Windows with "Fast Boot" enabled. That screws up NTFS filesystems so Windows boots faster. Disable "Fast Boot". Warning: some Windows updates turn Fast Boot back on behind your back.

Comment: The Linux NTFSfix does not do much. It really just sets the chkdsk flag so that Windows will run chkdsk on Windows boot. You probably had Windows fast start up on, so it left the NTFS partitions with the hibernation flag set. You have to turn off Windows hibernation. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @jpbrain i can not see the unity

Comment: @waltinator i just used windows (my friend computer) one time, now i am using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @Oldfred i want to use my external hdd in my ubuntu 20.04

Comment: ok. we need more information. Is the hdd spining up ok (watch lights)? is it a laptop or desktop computer? also what kind of hdd is it?

Comment: @jpbrain its a toshiba, its a external hdd, i use that hdd as a external, it is spinning fine

Comment: if the drive is running ok. you should see it with "gparted" or "disks" even if not mounted. Once you see it, we can move ahead and give you some help. Please, also try "sudo fdisk -l or sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb1" on a terminal and post that into the question.

Comment: @jpbrain but i need my information of my disk, what can i do? my disk still is fine or its break?

Comment: Yes. We are trying to get there. I use Ubuntu for years with external and shared NTFS drives with windows. So I am trying to get the information to help you. please, connect the drive and execute the commands above. If you drive was /dev/sdb, should be "sudo fdisk -l /dev/sbd"

Comment: ok. disk seems to be ok. Click on the gears and do "repair filesystem". then mount.

Comment: @jpbrain i found Create disk image, restore disk image, Benchmark Disk, which option can i select?

Comment: @jpbrain also i would like to know how to repair with gparted, i put a new image about gparted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128756/discussion-between-jpbrain-and-userstack).

Comment: Your fdisk shows a typical damaged partition table from writing an ISO using dd onto it. That totally overwrites everything in the first 4GB of drive or size of ISO. Generally better to just reformat drive & restore from backups. You may be able to recover some data with photorec, but if NTFS, they say Windows tools (maybe paid) will work better.

Comment: @oldfred i didn't try that, i never used dd or iso, my hdd is fine or is break?

Comment: Something wrote garbage into partition table. If you had used gpt, you might have the backup partition table that is at end of drive. But you are showing MBR(msdos) partitioning. You can first try testdisk to see if it finds any partitions. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk If you have to use photorec, you need another drive with enough space for all your files. Photorec is not just for recovery of photos, but it only recovers files by type, not including filename. You have to manually rename everything.

Comment: of jpbrain picture hdd its similar MBR see please https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIxMh.png